# Facebook push not working

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, facebook, apns

I have an iPhone 4 with iOS5 and Facebook and Messenger push notifications are not working for me, or they're delivered hours after they should be.

I had jailbrake on iOS 4.x and always assumed that was the case for me not getting push notifications, but the problem is here again on a freshly restored phone with iOS5. All my settings are correct (i.e. notifications are on etc.), I tried the same thing on an iPad 2 with iOS5 and notifications work instantly.

Answer (score 2):

You are experiencing something most of us do – the Facebook push notification server is notoriously unreliable. See [this Daily Buggle article](http://www.thedailybuggle.com/how-to-get-facebook-push-notifications-on-iphone-without-using-the-facebook-app/) for both confirmation and a possible workaround using [Boxcar](http://boxcar.io/).